# excel vba - removing duplicates from an array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to remove duplicate elements from an excel array. I imagine I'm not doing this in the most efficient way, and it doesn't seem to be working anyways:

```
For lrw = 1 To UBound(rcArray)
    For copyIndex = lrw + 1 To .Rows.Count
        If rcArray(copyIndex) = rcArray(lrw) Then
            rcArray(lrw).Delete
        End If
    Next copyIndex
Next lrw
```

Do I need to reDim the array? Does anyone have a link to some code for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `rcArray` declared as? If it's declared as an array then this `rcArray(lrw).Delete` won't work and will throw an error.

Comment: You could dump this to a range, extract the unique records using Excel's in built capability, and then dump the records back to a second array. The same method can be used for a data sort rather than bubble sorting an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it would take me a while to cobble up some code the best bet would be to create a new array and copy the values you want to keep to it. You can't just delete elements in the middle of an array.

Redim only allows you to add or remove elements from the end of the array.

Comment: so if it gets though a value, I copy it to a new array? Makes sense I think. Do I need to set the bounds of the array before I copy any values over?

Comment: Yes you copy it to the new array - you will need to have a separate index) and yes set the bounds to be the same as the initial array. Then when you are done you can truncate it using redim (keep track of how many items you copy over)